# How to register System.Net.CookieContainer using Windsor Castle?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have component in which I have dependency to CookieContaier object.
I managed to make this work by this code:

```
ICookieContainerFactory factory = container.Resolve<ICookieContainerFactory>();
container.AddFacility<FactorySupportFacility>()
         .Register(Component.For<System.Net.CookieContainer>()
         .UsingFactoryMethod(() => factory.GetCookieContainer())
         .LifeStyle.Singleton);
```

But I want to have this things in my configuration file.
How should I write this in my config?

I tried this way:

```
<component id="CookieContainerFactory"
               service="ABZ.RFOA.Core.Utility.ICookieContainerFactory, ABZ.RFOA.Core"
               type="ABZ.RFOA.Core.Utility.CookieContainerFactory, ABZ.RFOA.Core">
</component>
<component id="CookieContainer"
           type="System.Net.CookieContainer, System"
           factoryId="CookieContainerFactory"
           factoryCreate="GetCookieContainer"
           lifestyle="singleton"> 
</component>
```

But it's throwing me exception:

> Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Conversion.ConverterException : Could not convert from 'System.Net.CookieContainer, System' to System.Type - Maybe type could not be found

I don't understand what System.Type is doing here. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the assembly qualified name

`System.Net.CookieContainer, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`

instead of just `System.Net.CookieContainer, System`

Comment: Thanks, you're life saver. I would vote 10 times if it was possible. :)